# Native function that returns substring within a delimited string?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What native function can I use to retrieve a specific substring in a comma-delimited string?

For example, I have the following:

```
declare @table table
(
    mystring varchar(100)
)
Insert into @table 
select 'a,ff,sddd,sds,qwq' union
select 'a,jgj,sddd,sasds,qwq' union
select 'ccc,g,rer,fd,vs' union
select 'sdsd,xxx,rerqq,fdf,vsw'
```

Using some native function (maybe a combination of (ie. `PATINDEX`,  `STRING_SPLIT`, `CHARINDEX`), I'd like to return the string between the 2nd and third comma in all the rows.

The reason I'm asking about native functions is because I've seen several *custom* functions that work well with small batches of data (ie. `GetSplitString_CTE`) but they're extremely slow with large data sets.

I'm using `SQL Server 2016` and the source table has 1.7 billion rows. I cannot change the column type or add columns.

Comment: Don't use such comma separated strings in the first place. Use columns or rows in tables.

Comment: The source table has 1.7 billion rows. Do you want me to tell them to change it?

Comment: A sane data design could help tremendously in a lot of aspects around working with the data... So yes, changing that could be very beneficial in the future and worth the effort.

Comment: Average 5 items with average 4 characters each. 20 bytes + 4 commas + 2 bytes length, total 26 bytes average. In separate rows requires 4 + 2 each, total 30. So only 15% larger, but indexed and accessed far more efficiently. For example, 1.7b rows * 5 in a B-Tree requires an average 33 lookups. But the current schema requires a full table scan to do such a lookup.

Answer (score 2):

**A series of `CROSS APPLY`s feeding into each other should do the trick:**

```sql
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(
        t.mystring,
        v2.comma + 1,
        ISNULL(v3.comma - v2.comma - 1, LEN(t.mystring))
    )
FROM @table t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', t.mystring              ), 0) ) v1(comma)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', t.mystring, v1.comma + 1), 0) ) v2(comma)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', t.mystring, v2.comma + 1), 0) ) v3(comma)
```

Take the string `a,jgj,sddd,sasds,qwq`:

- `v1.comma` returns `2`
- `v2.comma` returns `6`
- `v3.comma` returns `11`
- The substring starts at `v2.comma + 1 = 7` and length of `v3.comma - v2.comma - 1 = 4`
- `NULLIF` in case `CHARINDEX` does not find a comma
- `ISNULL/LEN` in case there is no third comma

---

I strongly suggest you reconsider the table design

Answer (score 1):

With a bit a JSON

**Example**

```
Select A.* 
      ,Pos3 = JSON_VALUE('["'+replace(replace(mystring,'"','\"'),',','","')+'"]','$[2]')
from @table A
```

**Returns**

```
mystring                Pos3
a,ff,sddd,sds,qwq       sddd
a,jgj,sddd,sasds,qwq    sddd
ccc,g,rer,fd,vs         rer
sdsd,xxx,rerqq,fdf,vsw  rerqq
```

**NOTE:** If you can GTD no DOUBLE QUOTES in your string, you can eliminate one `replace()`

```
Select A.* 
      ,Pos3 = JSON_VALUE('["'+replace(mystring,',','","')+'"]','$[2]')
from @table A
```

**EDIT:  If you want to extact more than one value**

```
Select A.* 
      ,Pos1  = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[0]')
      ,Pos2  = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]')
      ,Pos3  = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[2]')
      ,Pos4  = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[3]')
      ,Pos5  = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[4]')
      ,Pos6  = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[5]')
From @table A
Cross Apply ( values ( '["'+replace(replace(A.mystring,'"','\"'),',','","')+'"]' ) ) B(S)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: I like it, never thought of parsing using json. Tried this for fun against a large table of data I have but get `JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '"' is found at position 1` - weird thing is that nothing contains a `"`

Comment: @sTTu Did you try the first option where we escape the double quotes?

Comment: Using it verbatim from your post. Problem was a backslash \

Comment: @sTTu  Ah... then you have to escape the backslash  ... \\

Comment: Yeah, and it looks like several other characters break it like char(13) - but that's just my data :) Had to escape several other characters for it to work, on my data set (1.5m rows) it take 1 sec for string_split method, 5 secs for json.

Comment: @sTTu Good to know,  just for fun, I'll run some benchmarks later.  I just don't understand why MS did not provide a sequence in string_split()  ... seemed elementary to me.

Comment: I agree, would have been so useful and probably so easy to do. Just for fun I tried offset fetch, that's terrible, row_number takes 1 sec against all rows to return 12k rows with a string at the chosen position while offset_fetch takes 25 seconds due to a sort and spool!!

Comment: @sTTu You got me curious.  On 10K newid()s, split on '-' .  My machine JSON is twice as fast, and average 84ms vs 223ms but DBFiddle shows my 20ms slower.   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8d4f3908f23b181500583c6253ce69ec

Comment: Interesting, I guess there's a lot of "it depends" thrown in there! I'll try a similar test at some point, I have 2016 and 2019 so will see if there's any differences.

Answer (score 1):

So using a built-in function as you requested, you can easily do that with `row_number()`

There is a caveat that according to the documentation the output is not *guaranteed* to be in order, but is in my experience; you could always replace it with your own function.

```
declare @x varchar(100)='a,bb,c,ddd,e,fff,ggggg,h,i'

select value from (
    select * , Row_Number() over (order by (select 1/0)) rn
    from String_Split(@x,',')
)s
where rn=5
```

You can implement easy against a table as

```
select * from
MyTable t outer apply
(
    select * , Row_Number() over (order by (select 1/0)) rn
    from String_Split(t.columnname,',')
)s
where rn=5
```