# Extract everything after the nth occurrence of a character

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

In SQL Server 2017 I have a string like

`GSLO¥10-00950000207406¥61500¥CRS15596859¥20220714153630¥2022-07-14¥¥¥¥¥¥¥63031¥0¥¥79087¥6793¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥`

and I would like to extract everything after the 11th appearence of the special character ¥.  In Oracle I can use `regexp_substr()`.  What is the equivalent in SQL Server?

Comment: Maybe successive `CHARINDEX` calls, see eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66681927/native-function-that-returns-substring-within-a-delimited-string/66683699#66683699